# Do I need to use separate 3D modeling software to create 3D models or is there an alternative easy way of creating them to use in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and still learning it. I want to make a simple game (i.e. shooting game).

I want to show a gun object as a shooting source.

My question is: **Do I need to design the object in seperate software like Blender or Maya? If so, is there any other easy way of creating 3D object models for Unity 3D?**

Comment: You can only create primitives(cube, sphere....) in unity. You need to use maya or 3d MAX to edit vertex, edge or faces.

Comment: Blender is also free and works well with unity, easy? well it depends how complex a shape, but there are a lot of tutorials out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of preference.

Assuming it is a 3D game and you want to work with 3D objects, you will need a object 3D model. Common object models types are STL, OBJ, FBX, COLLADA, 3DS, IGES; STEP, and VRML/X3D. Usually softwares have their specific "project file" and are able to export to one of those formats.

Softwares like Blender, 3DsMax and Maya can indeed export to those formats, but there are also "Unity-Only" approaches such as [ProBuilder](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/probuilder) or even using Unity's own primitive 3D objects (see [Unity - PrimitiveObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrimitiveObjects.html)).

You could also download free assets or buy models. I am pretty sure you are able to find free gun models online. Also, there are some specific software that are made to produce specific kinds of 3D models (e.g. [MagicaVoxel](https://ephtracy.github.io/) for producing voxel art)

Given all that information, I think **ProBuilder** is what you are looking for. ("an easy way of creating 3D objects for Unity").